# How to get STACKMOB_PUBLIC_KEY in StackMob

Tags: stackmob

I am using stackmob in Titanium....
I wanna give STACKMOB_PUBLIC_KEY, STACKMOB_PRIVATE_KEY, STACKMOB_APP_NAME, STACKMOB_USER_OBJECT_NAME in the code for authentication....

Can some one help me how to get these???

Thanks...

Comment: I got the answer for it... We can get the details in the Manage App section....

Answer (score 1):

You can find most of this information on the Manage Application info page:
https://www.stackmob.com/platform/account/apps/reset

By default the STACKMOB_USER_OBJECT_NAME is "user".  You can confirm this by visiting https://www.stackmob.com/platform/api/schemas/ .  You should see a schema called "user" and if you click edit for that schema you will see the following section:

**Schema Name and Type**

Schema Name:     user
Created as a User Object:    Yes

If you have set up your own user schema, then replace "user" with that schema name.

Comment: For more information on user schemas, see https://www.stackmob.com/devcenter/docs/User-Schemas